# R - Boxplot x-axis without ticks and complete

Tags: r, boxplot

I want to create a boxplot that simply has a x-axis without ticks and is drawn completely like on this example:
[target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJzEl.png)

So far I could create something like this: 
[current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pJPp.png)

The call looks like this:

```
#load data
deckung_BS1 <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=T, sep=';', check.names = FALSE)

#draw boxplot without x-axis
boxplot(deckung_BS1, main="Deckung Baumschicht 1", ylab="Deckung [%]", boxwex=.5, xaxt='n', frame=FALSE)

#put x-axis without ticks
axis(side = 1,at = 1:3,labels=c("1960 (n=19)", "2002 (n=19)", "2012 (n=19)"),lwd.ticks = FALSE)
```

So the question is how can I draw a complete line for the x-axis without ticks?

Comment: Please make your example reproducible (use e.g. `boxplot(Petal.Length ~ Species, iris)`)

Comment: Sorry my csv-file has three columns with data from three different years. I'm not sure how to make it reproducible. The data is the light-coverage for 19 different spots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `base` R solution:

```
boxplot(data.frame(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10), c = rnorm(10)), xaxt='n', frame=FALSE)
axis(side = 1,at = 0:4,labels=c("", "a", "b", "c", ""),lwd.ticks = FALSE)
```

[image]

The key is to add empty labels left and right of your actual data..

**Edit after comment**

If not specified otherwise, the axes are computed. Read `?barplot` for details. If you want your `y-axis` to end on the `x-axis` you have to specify a range that is "lower" than the `x-axis`.

```
set.seed(2)
boxplot(data.frame(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10), c = rnorm(10)), xaxt='n', yaxt='n', frame=FALSE)
axis(side = 1,at = 0:4,labels=c("", "a", "b", "c", ""),lwd.ticks = FALSE)
axis(side = 2,at = -3:2)
```

Notice that the "range" of the `y-axis` is set to `-3:2`, while the data (and the plot area ends at about `-2`.

[image]

Comment: perfect.. just one more question? why does the y-axis not end on the x-axis?

Comment: @basto `box(bty = 'l')` would also fill in the gap

Comment: @rawr: actually that was the command I was looking for, perfect! thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `ggplot` solution:

```
library(ggplot2) 

ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = class, y = hwy)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=1),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

[image: boxplot]

In particular, `axis.ticks.x  = element_blank()` removes the ticks.  The other theme elements are not strictly necessary to answer your question, they just approximate the plain white background and black border of the base R `boxplot()` function.

In your case, use `data = deckung_BS1`, and then specify whatever your `x` and `y` variables are within your data.

See [`geom_boxplot()`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_boxplot.html) docs for more details.

Comment: thx for this solution, but I prefer the base solution due to it's simplicity